How to use lambda functions in COQ
I'm struggling with the basic syntax and I'm going to need to see some examples. I get the impression that I need to declare a polymorphic type param.
Notation "'λ' x .. y , t" := (fun x => .. (fun y => t) ..)
  (at level 10, x binder, y binder, t at level 200,
  format "'[  ' '[  ' 'λ'  x  ..  y ']' ,  '/' t ']'").

Definition Identity       := λ"x",     "x".
Notation   "I"            := Identity.
Check       I.

Syntax error: [open_binders] expected after 'λ' (in [term]).

I'm also trying to do something which I think would be more idiomatic in COQ, but with even less success:
Require Import Int.
Require Import ZArith.
Open Scope Int_scope.

Definition double (n : Z) : Z := n * 2.
Definition half   (n : Z) : Z := n / 2.

(* n = (a+b)(a+b) = (a*a) + (2*a*b) + (b*b) *)

Fixpoint square   (n : Z) : nat := match n with
| 0 => 0
| n => square(half(n)) + double(half(n) * (n - half(n))) + square(n - half(n))
end.

Lemma square_n_n :
  forall (n : Z),
    square(n) = n * n.
Proof.
  intro n.
  unfold square.
  reflexivity.
Qed.

Close Scope Int_scope.

Found a constructor of inductive type nat while a constructor of Z is expected


What are you trying to do?
The first example does not work for several reasons, one of them is that variable names should not be in quotes (i.e. write fun x => x not fun "x" => "x"), the other is that it's not clear what the type of Identity should be.
The second example does not work either for several reasons, the first being that you open Int_scope but then use Z (try Z_scope instead), another being that you mix Z and nat in a way that seems broken, and finally that your Fixpoint square is not structurally recursive (you would need well-founded recursion).

These are two questions.  Please ask them separately.

For the first part of the question
There are two problems.
First, at the syntactic level, the notation is okay, but when some sub expression expects a binder, it cannot be a constant like "x", it should be just a name.
So your definition of identity should be :
Definition Identity := λ x, x. (* this still fails. *)

But then comes the second problem.  Coq does not accept defining a function from a type to a type, without knowing what this type is.  Here I don't really know what your intention is.  For instance, I could do an identity where the type is an implicit argument that should be filled when the context gives enough information:
Definition Identity {T : Type} : T -> T := λ x, x.

This function can then be used in contexts where it is applied to 3 and true, where T will be computed to be nat and bool respectively.
For the second part of the question
The answer is simple: don't use Int_scope but Z_scope instead.
The scope machinery acts like a stack.  By default, nat_scope is open.  When you open another scope, that new scope is placed on top of the stack, but nat_scope is still present below it.
The scope Int_scope does not declare a notation for 0, so when the parser is facing the expression 0, it asks Int_scope what should be the interpretation, and this scope does not have an answer, so nat_scope is interrogated, and this one returns the value O, which is a constructor for nat.  But you wrote a pattern matching expression for a value of type Z.  Hence the error message.
Don't use Int or Int_scope.  This module contains comments explaining that this a lightweight interface for something very specialized (MSetAVL).  It is not meant to be used as background for introduction experiments in Coq.
If you replace Int_scope with Z_scope, then your code fragment shows another error: you define a function square of type Z -> nat, but you use it at a place where the value should be Z, so that raises another type error.  The fix is to change you definition to say that you want to return a value of type Z.  But then, you will encounter yet another problem: you cannot define a one-argument recursive function on Z using Fixpoint.  To understand this you need to have more training on what are structurally recursive functions in Coq.  I suggest you look at Coq in a hurry (page 6, 9, 27).  This document explains that you can only use Fixpoint when the inductive type on which you are working has constructors that take as argument values in the same type.
If we look at the type Z, we can ask Coq to display its definition by typing Print Z..  The result is:
Inductive Z : Set :=  Z0 : Z | Zpos : positive -> Z | Zneg : positive -> Z.

This shows that Z has 3 constructors, one constructor has no argument, and the other two constructors have an argument from another type.  Since the rule of recursion on inductive types is that you can only call yourself on subterms that are in the type Z, you will not be able to define a structurally recursive function on type Z.
There are ways to circumvent this limitation.  The basic approach is define structurally recursive functions on type positive.  This requires a little thinking, because the constructors of positive have meaning 1, multiply by 2, and multiply by 2 and add one.  So, when you write a recursive function, this means you are only allowed recursive calls on the half of your initial argument.  But this actually is the spirit of the algorithm you want to write.  You should try this technique.
When recursion limited to the half of non-zero numbers is not powerful enough for your needs, there are more techniques available, like adding a fuel argument, using well-founded recursion, or using the Equation plugin.
